# A distant riddle

Tags: riddle

> Sometimes island in the middle of the blue sea
>
> Other times sea in the middle of the valley
>
> For I can be artificial or natural
>
> Those that can read me may see the future

Who can I be?

Comment: first time writing a riddle and not a native speaker,  please don't hesitate to correct!

Comment: Not bad for an non-native speaker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> A cloud

Sometimes island in the middle of the blue sea

> Sometimes, clouds are isolated in the middle of the blue sky

Other times sea in the middle of the valley

> Other times, the sky is entirely covered with clouds, except for a few patches of blue

For I can be artificial or natural

> Clouds can be created artificially, but most are natural. "Artificial clouds" may also be a reference to cloud computing

Those that can read me may see the future

> <s>Some people look for clouds that are shaped like certain things</s> If you pay attention to the clouds, you can tell whether it's likely to rain or not

Title

> Clouds are several miles up in the sky

Other

> The first letter of every line spells out "S O F T", which clouds most certainly are.

Comment: You are right on your answer. But the two last clues could be analyzed a different way. Can you find it?

Comment: Thought of something for the third line, not sure about the last line...

Comment: Sometimes I look a them and I think : "Maybe it would be safer to take my umbrella"

Comment: I believe I understand the last two clues. What is the etiquette - answer myself, or suggest here?

Comment: I think the etiquette is generally to suggest in comments, using ROT13 to avoid partial spoilers. I think I've got the last line now, though.

Comment: Well done. ;) To be honest I knew that the two last clues could be understood both way. So I would have accepted your answer anyway

Answer (score 4):

I guess its an:

> Illusion

Sometimes island in the middle of the blue sea.

> Often we see in documentaries and movies that people who get stranded in middle of sea or an ocean they get illusions of islands in middle of the water body.

Other times sea in the middle of the valley

> Mirage, a phenomenon in which people see water bodies in between dry areas, valley or deserts.

For I can be artificial or natural

> For those can sometime be real too.

Those that can read me may see the future

> not sure about this?

Comment: No that's not the answer sorry. But it is a nice answer tho

Answer (score 4):

You are:

> A cloud

Sometimes island in the middle of the blue sea
Other times sea in the middle of the valley

> As answered by @Maniraj this refers to the phenomena of a single cloud against a blue sky, and a gap of blue sky in a clouded sky.

For I can be artificial or natural

> As well as naturally occurring clouds comprising of water vapour, "clouds" can also be of smoke, created by man-made fires.

Those that can read me may see the future

> I believe this refers to *Aeromancy* - the belief that you can tell the future from reading cloud patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> A remote (control)

Sometimes island in the middle of the blue sea

> That's a *remote* desert island, or a *remote* control in the middle of a sea of clutter.

Other times sea in the middle of the valley

> That's a lake in a valley among a *remote* region of a mountain chain, or a *remote* that's fallen between the couch cushions.

For I can be artificial or natural

> Remote controls are artificial; remote desert islands are natural.

Those that can read me may see the future

> If you use your remote to turn on Closed Captioning in a movie or a TV show, sometimes you can read a caption before it is spoken, and thus learn about a joke or a plot twist several seconds before the viewer is supposed to know about it.

Title

> **A distant riddle**:  Remote controls are called "remotes" because the control things from far away (at a distance); remote desert islands are called "remote" because they're far away (very distant).

Other

> If a remote control has a fast-forward feature, you can see the future of the film or TV show you're watching.